# Setting border property to li - tag in html brings down the last li element to next line

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists, border

I have a requirement that navigation item in html header page to have a dashed border. I set the border property in css file. I got the dashed border to li element, but the problem is last li elements comes in next line.

This is my nav bar html code:

`<div class="navbardiv">
    <ul class="topnavbarlist">
    <li> <a>home</a> </li>
    <li> <a>store</a> </li>
    <li> <a>gallery</a> </li>
    <li> <a>about us</a> </li>
    <li> <a>sign in</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>`

Below is my CSS:

```
.topnavbarlist
{
 list-style: none;
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background:#cdeb8e;
list-style-type: none;
}
.topnavbarlist li{
float:left;
width:20%;
height:100%;
display:table-cell;
text-align: center;
list-style-type: none;
border: 1px dashed rgba(84,84,84,0.8);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the [box-model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box_model), by default the width is assigned to the content box so the 20% width is for the content and then the border is outside of it which will result in a width above 100%.

You can control this behavior using [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#Browser_compatibility) css property.

```css
.topnavbarlist {
    list-style: none;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#cdeb8e;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.topnavbarlist li {
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px dashed rgba(84, 84, 84, 0.8);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbardiv">
    <ul class="topnavbarlist">
        <li> <a>home</a> </li>
        <li> <a>store</a> </li>
        <li> <a>gallery</a> </li>
        <li> <a>about us</a> </li>
        <li> <a>sign in</a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to your `li` style. It well tell the browser to include the width of the border when calculating the size instead of adding the border around your specified width. [more info](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to reduce the width from 20% to 19%.